# how to create public function to insert into mysql using php n json data?

Tags: php, mysql, json, function

```
function insert_data($data, $table, $action )
{
    include "connect.php";

    $columnnvalues = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);

    $columns = array ();
    $values = array();
    foreach($columnnvalues as $key=>$col)
    {
        foreach($col as $keyval=>$val)
        {
            array_push($columns, $col);
            array_push($values, $val);
        }
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " .$table. " (" .implode(", ", $columns).") VALUES (".implode(", ", $values). ")";
    echo $sql;
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
    if($stmt)
    {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result["success"] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $result["success"] = false;
        $result["error"] = 1;
    }
    echo  json_encode($result);

}
```

sample datas

```
$datas = Array ("name"=>"sample", "permanentaddress"=>"add", "contact"=>"aaaa", "status"=>"Active");
insert_data($datas, "customers", "add" )
```

Comment: You've shown some PHP code here, which is good, but can you add some text to your question to explain what you're asking a bit more? Are you trying to add something new to this code, or to fix something that's not working right? Are there any errors?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Public Functions are a part of classes, it seems like you're missing some code! As @Don'tPanic said, you might want to add more detail about what kind of effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You take json_encode $data then json_decode it to fill in $columnnvalues. Whats the purpose of that? Also the prepare is not protecting you db.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.